why does react return UseState error in npm minified library
I have a library below that enables users to connect with a modal. The idea is to publish it as an SDK. Testing  works as expected locally, but when published on npm as an SDK library and tried implementing it, the minified js version gives the error below, how can I fix this?:

Source
../tokenbound-sdk/connector/dist/index-CWezfyUH.js (9907:0) @ Object.$t [as useState]

  9905 | function $t(T) {
  9906 |   var N = Le();
    ⁠9907 |   return N.useState(T);
  9908 | }
  9909 | function bt(T, N, q) {
  9910 |   var J = Le();


can anyone please suggest a fix?
TokenBoundModal.tsx
The token bound modal componenet
import React from 'react';
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { IModal } from '../connector/types/modal';

function TokenBoundModal({ isOpen, closeModal, value, selectedOption, handleChange, handleChangeInput, onConnect }: IModal) {
  const options = ['argentX', 'braavos'];
  return (
    <>
      <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={closeModal}>
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black/25" />
          </Transition.Child>

          <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
            <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center p-4 text-center">
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="ease-out duration-300"
                enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
                enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave="ease-in duration-200"
                leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
              >
                <Dialog.Panel className="w-full max-w-md transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left align-middle shadow-xl transition-all">
                  <div className='flex items-center justify-between mb-4'>
                  <Dialog.Title
                    as="h3"
                    className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                  >
                    Connect with tokenbound
                  </Dialog.Title>

                  <div onClick={closeModal} className='text-black cursor-pointer'>X</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="w-full">
                    <label className='text-black mb-2 block' htmlFor="tba-address">Token bound address</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="TBA ADDRESS"
                      id='tba-address'
                      value={value}
                      onChange={handleChangeInput}
                      className="w-full border border-gray-300 bg-white text-black rounded px-3 py-2 mb-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500"
                    />
                    <select
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={selectedOption}
                      className="w-full border border-gray-300 bg-white text-black rounded px-3 py-2 mb-3 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500"
                    >
                      <option value="id">Select parent wallet</option>
                      {options.map((option, index) => (
                        <option key={index} value={option}>
                          {option}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <button onClick={onConnect} className='w-full text-white bg-[#0C0C4F] border-gray-500 outline-none p-2'>Connect with token bound account</button>
                </Dialog.Panel>
              </Transition.Child>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    </>
  )
}

export default TokenBoundModal;

hooks.ts
the hooks that controls the state of the modal and submit logic
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function useTokenBoundModal() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const resetInputValues = () => {
    setValue("");
    setSelectedOption("");
  };

  return {
    isOpen,
    openModal,
    closeModal,
    value,
    selectedOption,
    handleChange,
    handleChangeInput,
    resetInputValues
  };
}

export default useTokenBoundModal;

implementation

The default local implementation fails when the connector is installed. can anyone please suggest a fix
  const {
    isOpen,
    openModal,
    closeModal,
    value,
    selectedOption,
    handleChange,
    handleChangeInput,
    resetInputValues,
  } = useTokenBoundModal();

  const tokenbound = new TokenboundConnector({
    tokenboundAddress: value,
    parentAccountId: selectedOption,
  });

  const connectTBA = async () => {
    const connection = await tokenbound.connect();
    closeModal();
    resetInputValues();

    if (connection && connection.isConnected) {
      setConnection(connection);
      setAccount(connection.account);
      setAddress(connection.selectedAddress);
    }
  };

 {isOpen && (
        <TokenBoundModal
          isOpen={isOpen}
          closeModal={closeModal}
          value={value}
          selectedOption={selectedOption}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          handleChangeInput={handleChangeInput}
          onConnect={connectTBA}
        />
      )}
    ```

